# Kibana not populating results

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, kibana-5

I am able to create an index in ElasticSearch., but when I try to visualize in Kibana, I am able to create the particular index accordingly and open the visualization chart, and when I try to visualize for any field, results are not appearing (it is appearing as ?)

[image]

But I am able to visualize data calc. for the fields if I do not mention date field in the document.

```
PUT culturalssq
{
"mappings": {
"sss":{
"properties": {
"event":{"type":"string"},
"venue":{"type":"string"},
"type":{"type": "string"},
"about":{"type":"string"},
"reg_fee":{"type": "integer"},
"music_type":{"type":"string"},
"link_url":{"type":"string"},
"number_of_seats":{"type":"integer"},
"datetime":{"type":"date","format":"dateOptionalTime"}
}
}
}
}

PUT culturalssq/sss/1
{
    "event":"SPOT Festival 2014",
    "venue":"music academy",
    "type":"Instrumental Music",
    "about":"Spot festival event 2014",
    "reg_fee":900,
    "music_type":"Standup/Comedy",
    "link_url":"http://www.billetlugen.dk/referer/?r=266abe1b7fab4562a5c2531d0ae62171&p=/koeb/billetter/29210/46785/",
    "number_of_seats":60,
    "datetime":"2009-11-15T14:12:12"
}

PUT culturalssq/sss/2
{
    "event":"8000 Comedy",
    "venue":"music academy",
    "type":"Comedy show",
    "about":"Comedy Event",
    "reg_fee":223,
    "music_type":"Gratis",
    "link_url":"http://www.billetlugen.dk/referer/?r=266abe1b7fab4562a5c2531d0ae62171&p=/koeb/billetter/33252/47481/",
    "number_of_seats":99,
    "datetime":"2009-11-15T14:12:12"
}

PUT culturalssq/sss/3
{
    "event":"Music Show",
    "venue":"Narada Gana",
    "type":"event show",
    "about":"music Event",
    "reg_fee":222,
    "music_type":"Pop",
    "link_url":"http://www.billetlugen.dk/referer/?r=266abe1b7fab4562a5c2531d0ae62171&p=/koeb/billetter/33252/47481/",
    "number_of_seats":222,
    "datetime":"2009-11-15T14:12:12"
}
```

Can anyone help here why am I getting this issue? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's due to the `datetime` field where your results an year old. Hence in your `Visualize` window, on your top left hand corner, try giving the `timespan` as last two years and refresh.

[image]